# How to load a smart contract which has been deployed in ganache-cli in remix?

Tags: remix, ganache-cli

I have deployed a smart contract in ganache-cli. How can I interact with it using remix? Currently remix is saying **"No compiled contracts found."** when I try to load my smart contract with deployed address.
Thank you for any kind of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To interact with your smart contract deployed in ganache-cli using Remix, you need to make sure that **Remix** is connected to the same Ethereum network as your ganache-cli instance. Here are the steps:

Open Remix in your web browser.

Go to the "Run" tab.

In the "Environment" dropdown, select "**Web3 Provider**".

In the "Web3 Provider Endpoint" field, enter the URL of your ganache-cli instance. This is usually **"http://localhost:8545"** but you can check in your ganache as well it might be **7545** as well.

Click "Connect".

Once connected, you should be able to load your smart contract using its deployed **address** and **ABI** (Application Binary Interface).